# How do I make a ERC-20 token untransferable?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

How Do I make a token untransferable by the wallet owner and only transferable by the token smart contract

Answer (score 0):

A contract can never initiate a transaction, so you cannot make the token "transferable by the contract." It must always be done by an external wallet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `make a token untransferable by the wallet owner`, you can kill the contract or prohibit the contract owner to transfer. But it's likely not possible to have `only transferable by the token smart contract` at the same time.